# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry' for key Unique data field using UPDATE. MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to add a stored procedure for my Java project that communicates with a MYSQL database.

When I try to edit a department record in my database it gives me an error code 1062 which states that there is a duplicate entry.

After doing some searching it's clear that the error is due to the departmentName being a unique field.

Not sure how to overcome this problem since the solutions online didn't help me.

So far I've turned off save mode and tried to add an IGNORE statement between UPDATE and department but that would just incorrectly force the new record into position 1 of the table (overwriting whatever was there).

Let's assume that my database holds the following data:

```
DID  -  departmentName
  3  -  Basketball
  1  -  CS
  2  -  English
```

If in my department table I want to change the departmentName in DID 1 to Math. It will give me that error message if I use the new stored procedure that I created.  Yet this works fine with my manual call to the database from Java.

(Error Code)

07:50:09    call piercecollege.updateDepartment(1, 'Math')  Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'Math' for key 'departmentName_UNIQUE'    0.062 sec

```
(MYSQL workbench procedure)
CREATE DEFINER=`autofakt5`@`%` PROCEDURE `updateDepartment`(
IN dID int,
IN dName varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE department
SET 
departmentName = dName

WHERE DID = dID;

END
```

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw2qD.jpg)

```
    CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `DID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `departmentName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DID_UNIQUE` (`DID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `departmentName_UNIQUE` (`departmentName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my stored procedure

```
  (Stored Procedure call in JAVA)
    public void updateDepartmentMYSQL(Department temp) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e2) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not connect to the database");
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        CallableStatement statement = null;

        try {
            int dID = temp.getDID();
            String dName = temp.getDepartmentName();
            
            
            statement = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call 
       updateDepartment(" 
            +String.valueOf(dID) +",'" + dName +"')}");
            System.out.println(statement);
            
            statement.execute();
            
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
    }
```

Which replaced this working manual call to the database.

```
public void updateDepartmentMYSQLREPLACED(Department editedDepartment) { //replaced with procedure
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Could not connect to the database");
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }

    String sqlStatement = "UPDATE department " + "SET departmentName = '" + editedDepartment.getDepartmentName()
            + "' " + "WHERE DID = " + String.valueOf(editedDepartment.getDID()) + ";";
    System.out.println(sqlStatement);
    int rows = 0;
    try {
        rows = stmt.executeUpdate(sqlStatement);
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(rows + " row(s) added to the table.");
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: 'With the IGNORE modifier, the update statement does not abort even if errors occur during the update. Rows for which duplicate-key conflicts occur on a unique key value are not updated' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Please add table definition as text to the question.

Comment: I added the Create Table statement.  Is that considered the definition also?

Comment: I am not clear what the problem is the error is being thrown as expected - probably on an id other than 1 are you trying to allocate math from another id to id = 1?

Comment: My studentManagement program allows for the user to enter a school department name.   Once that's been completed, this particular procedure is supposed to edit the existing department record by allowing the department name (departmentName) field to change at the particular DID (department ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a helpful error message - don't give parameters the same name as columns. change dID to in_dID and change the where clause to

WHERE DID = in_dID;

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.174 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> DELIMITER $$
MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE PROCEDURE `P`(
    -> IN indID int,
    -> IN dName varchar(45)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    -> UPDATE t
    -> SET Name = dName
    -> WHERE DID = indID;
    -> end $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.101 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> DELIMITER ;
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+------+-------------+
| did  | name        |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | MATHEMATICS |
|    2 | science     |
+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CALL P(1,'MATH');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.025 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+------+---------+
| did  | name    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | MATH    |
|    2 | science |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Yea that fixed it. Thanks a lot. I usually never do that with variable names but thought I was safe with case sensitivity this time.